# Условие в strpos

Tags: php

```
    $filter = function ($arr, $data, $find, $comm = null) {
        return array_filter($arr, function ($item) use ($data, $find, $comm) {
            if (strpos($item->data, $data) !== false && strpos($item->comm, $comm) !== false){
                return in_array($item->kod, $findArray);
            }
        });
    };
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в метод приходит параметр $comm и код работает как надо, но бывает что параметр $comm пустой и тогда ошибка в `strpos($item->comm, $comm) !== false`, помогите решить проблему...

Comment: а какое поведение ожидается, если $comm пустой?

Comment: Пропустить условие strpos($item->comm, $comm) !== false

Comment: допишите в начало условия `if (!empty($comm) && ....`

Comment: Нужно пропустить не все условие, а только часть его, где strpos($item->comm, $comm) !== false

Comment: `if (strpos($item->data, $data) !== false) { if (empty($comm) ||  (!empty($comm) && strpos($item->comm, $comm) !== false))   { return in_array($item->kod, $findArray);  }}`  --- такое ??

Comment: Да, именно, спасибо